# c++ algorithm for running a command after detecting square

Tags: c++, opencv

I have opencv code for detecting square. And now I want after detect square, the code run another command.

Here is the code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

double angle( CvPoint* pt1, CvPoint* pt2, CvPoint* pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1->x - pt0->x;
    double dy1 = pt1->y - pt0->y;
    double dx2 = pt2->x - pt0->x;
    double dy2 = pt2->y - pt0->y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
} // angle

IplImage* findSquares4(  IplImage* img,  CvMemStorage* storage )
{
    double s = 0,  t = 0;
    int sdetect =0, sqdetect = 0,sqt = 0;
    CvSeq* contours;
    CvSeq* result;
    CvSeq* squares  =  cvCreateSeq(  0,  sizeof( CvSeq),  sizeof( CvPoint),  storage );

    IplImage* cny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);

    cvCanny(img, cny, 5, 100, 3);

    cvNamedWindow("canny",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("canny",cny);

    cvFindContours(  cny,  storage,  &contours,  sizeof( CvContour),  CV_RETR_LIST,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,  cvPoint( 0, 0) );

    while(  contours )
    {
        result  =  cvApproxPoly(    contours,
                                sizeof( CvContour),
                                storage,
                                CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,
                                cvContourPerimeter( contours)*0.02,  0 );

        if(  result->total  == 4 &&
             fabs( cvContourArea( result, CV_WHOLE_SEQ)) > 1000 &&
             cvCheckContourConvexity( result) )
        {
            s  =  0;
            for(  int i = 2; i < 5; i++ )
            {
                {
                    t  =  fabs( angle(
                                ( CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(  result,  i ),
                                ( CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(  result,  i-2 ),
                                ( CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(  result,  i-1 )));
                    s  =  s > t ? s : t;
                    cout << "s = " << s<< endl;
                    cout << "t = " << t<< endl;
                }
            } // for
            if(  s < 0.3 )
                for(  int i  =  0; i < 4; i++ )
                    cvSeqPush(  squares,
                          ( CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(  result,  i ));
        } // if

    contours  =  contours->h_next;

    } // while
    if ((squares->total/4) = 1)
    {
        sdetect = 1;
    } / /if
    else
    {
        sdetect = 2;
        sleep(0.5);
    } // else

    if (sqdetect != sdetect)
    {
        sqdetect=sdetect;
        switch(sqdetect)
        {
            case 0 : system(NULL) ; break;
            case 2 : cout<< "no "<< endl; break;
            case 1 : system("./ambil1.sh"); break;
        } // switch
    } // if
    sdetect = 0;

    cout<<"Persegi : "<< squares->total/4 <<endl;

    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
    cvClearSeq(squares);

} // findSquares4

void drawSquares(IplImage *img, CvSeq* squares )
{
    CvFont font;
    cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0,1, 8 );
    int i,j,sdetect,sqdetect = 0;
    CvSeqReader reader;
    cvStartReadSeq( squares, &reader, 0 );

    for( i = 0; i < squares->total; i += 4 )
    {
        j++;
        CvPoint pt[4], *rect = pt;
        int count = 4;

         // read 4 vertices
        memcpy( pt, reader.ptr, squares->elem_size );
        CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM( squares->elem_size, reader );
        memcpy( pt + 1, reader.ptr, squares->elem_size );
        CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM( squares->elem_size, reader );
        memcpy( pt + 2, reader.ptr, squares->elem_size );
        CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM( squares->elem_size, reader );
        memcpy( pt + 3, reader.ptr, squares->elem_size );
        CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM( squares->elem_size, reader );

        cvPutText( img, "SQUARE", pt[i], &font, CV_RGB(20,255,0));

        cvPolyLine( img, &rect, &count, 1, 1, CV_RGB(200,0,0), 4, CV_AA, 0 );
    } // for

cvClearSeq(squares);
}  // drawSquares
```

But what I got is that the program becomes laggy. So what is the right algorithm to place condition for executing `system (./ambil1.sh)`?

Answer (score 1):

The program waits until the subordinate command finishes. During this time it will not respond.

If that's what you need, `system` is adequate.

If you want to fire and forget, you can either use the `fork/exec` pair, or just use the shell `&` operator to run stuff in the background.

If you need to fire, change your program's behaviour, then change it back when the subordinate command finishes, you almost have to use the `fork/exec/SIGCHLD/waitpid` combination.

Comment: what do you mean by fire and forget?

Comment: Start the subordinate program and let it run in parallel with the main program, without any interaction between the two.